# IPv6 support in Payments Pro

Tags: paypal, ipv6

I am hoping you can all help me out real quick with this.  Based on the documentation for PayPal Payments Pro, the IP address is a required value.  However, it appears that PayPal does not yet support IPv6.  What should we send along as the IP address when the user has an IPv6 address instead of the older IPv4 address that PayPal supports?  We have had transactions declined due to an "invalid" format when the v6 address is sent, and it will only become worse as time goes on and more and more internet providers use IPv6.

From the documentation:

---

IPADDRESS (Required) IP address of the buyer's browser.
Note:

PayPal records this IP addresses as a means to detect possible fraud.

Character length and limitations: 15 single-byte characters, including periods, for example, 255.255.255.255

---

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should definitely do is to complain to PayPal about the rejection of IPv6. you can use many sorts of workarounds but the real solution should come from Paypal and they should support IPv6 in their payment system. One workaround is the converter, but you will have to sit in the middle and do the conversion:( http://ipv6.ztsoftware.net/ipv4-to-ipv6/ ) and you are not sure if that IPv4 is blacklisted :-)

Comment: This "converter" doesn't do anything relevant to this problem. The rest of your answer is fine.

Answer (score 1):

On March 6, 2013, [PayPal supposedly changed the API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/release-notes/merchant/PayPal_Merchant_API_Release_Notes_98/) to permit IPv6 and IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses in the IPADDRESS field.

> The IPADDRESS (NVP) and IPAddress (SOAP) field now accept IPv6 and IPv4-mapped IPv6 IP addresses in addition to IPv4 IP addresses.

Unfortunately [the documentation doesn't actually reflect this change](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoDirectPayment_API_Operation_NVP/). It seemed they only made the change to the [DoReferenceTransaction](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/) call, and not to the DoDirectPayment call or any other call. Which of course is completely useless. I would contact PayPal to report the problem.

Comment: In my testing, they still reject IPv6 addresses for DoDirectPayment.  As of one day ago anyway.  The error has shown up in my declined transaction log on PayPal.com as recently as yesterday afternoon (when I posted this question).  So, although they may have updated it for the DoReferenceTransaction call, the DoDirectPayment call has not yet been changed.

My workaround has been to send an empty IP address when it is a IPv6 address.  Although the documentation says that the IP address is "required", it doesn't seem to be.

Comment: Yep, it seems clear that PayPal _intends_ to support this, but that they haven't actually managed to implement it correctly. Not much that anyone but PayPal can do to resolve this.